# Calculate A double summation with control flow in an efficient way

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to calculate the following  [double sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NIV4.jpg) which calculates the chance of someone finishes 2nd in some sort of race given we have the chance of the individual finishes 1st. X being the length of the list of runners and also n!=i

The following code does the work

```
def Scnd(mylist=[]):
          
    sec=[]
    for seconds in range(len(mylist)):
       sum=0
       for firsts in range(len(mylist)):
           if firsts==seconds:
               pass
           else:
               sum_second=mylist[firsts]*(mylist[seconds]/(1-mylist[firsts]))
               sum+=sum_second
       sec.append(sum)
    print(sec)
    #do something with the list
```

with the following example

```
alist=[0.4,0.25,0.2,0.15]
Scnd(alist)
```

the result will be

```
[0.303921568627451, 0.2732843137254902, 0.23529411764705882, 0.1875]
```

I understand this code is really slow and I'm wondering about ways to make it faster (possibly a lot neater in the process too).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is much faster, but your function could be transformed to this:

```
def Scnd(mylist=[]):
    sec = [(sum(firsts/(1-firsts) for firsts in mylist) 
            - seconds/(1-seconds)) * seconds
              for seconds in mylist]
    print(sec)
```

Comment: Definitely neater but unfortunately not really faster. Thanks though